# Char size 8 bit or 16 bit?

Tags: java, char, byte

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html, char size is 16 bit i.e 2 byte.
somehow i recalled its 8 bit i.e 1 byte. To clear my doubt, i created a text file with single character "a"
and saved it. Then i inspected the size of file , its 1 byte i.e 8 bit. I am confused whats the size of
character ? If its 2 byte , why file size is 1 byte and if it is 1 byte why link says 2 bytes?

Comment: 1 character is 8 bits that is a byte

Comment: @AliGajani: That's simply untrue.

Comment: @AliGajani: Look at the language tag again and then consider how characters are encoded in Java. Even so, 8-bits is not necessarily a byte.

Comment: Yes, I realized it's Java. I was wrong earlier.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A `char` in Java is a [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) code unit. It's not necessarily a complete Unicode character, but it's effectively an unsigned 16-bit integer.

When you write text to a file (or in some other way convert it into a sequence of bytes), then the data will depend on which *encoding* you use. For example, if you use ASCII or ISO-8859-1 then you're very limited as to which characters you can write, but each character will only be a byte. If you use UTF-16, then each Java `char` will be converted into exactly two bytes - but some Unicode characters may take four bytes (those represented by two Java `char` values).

If you use [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), then the length of even a single Java `char` in the encoded form will depend on the value.

Comment: Is c1 one byte, c2 two bytes? `char c1 = (char) 255;
  char c2 = (char) 258;`

Comment: @Pingpong: No, `char` is a 16-bit data type whatever the value, just like `int` is a 32-bit data type whatever the value.

Answer (score 8):

There is a contemporary way to learn its size. Just print with `BYTES`.

```
System.out.println(Character.BYTES);
```

It results in `2`

Answer (score 0):

Note that text files really have a format/ character set associated with them. Text files will normally be saved in UTF-8 format which is 8 bits per character unless the character is "special".

Comment: What's your definition of "special"? *Anything* non-ASCII?

Comment: I was trying to keep my answer concise :-) for a full definition see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: When "concise" means using such a hideously vague term as "special character", I don't think it's much use.

Answer (score 0):

A char in Java is 2 bytes large (as the valid value range suggests). But it doesn't necessarily mean that every representation of a character is 2 bytes long. For instance, many encodings would only reserve 1 byte for every character (or use 1 byte for the most frequent characters).If the platform default encoding is a 1-byte encoding such as ISO-8859-1 or a variable-length encoding such as UTF-8, it can easily convert that 1 byte to a single character.